# Replace part of website URL stored in PHP variable

Tags: php, split, explode

I need to hide part of URL, in a php script, that have unlimited subdomains levels and characters, also the TLD can have one or more levels, for example: it can be health.blog.web.com.br or only site.net. Since the URLs are inside $website variable I thought that a good idea is get the variable value characters, divide by 2 and in the first part get the last three characters replaced by *** and in the second part get the first three character and replace also replace by ***. So in the examples above I would have health.b******b.com.br and s******t. I didn't think in nothing better to hide part of URLs. Is it possible to divide the variable and add the 6 asterisks? Or if you have a better idea please let me know, remembering that the value of $website is gave by the user and it can have from 4 to unlimited number of characters.

Comment: what does it mean by TLD ?

Comment: What I would try to do is pushing all the characters into an array and then go from there.

Comment: as  it can have from 4 to unlimited number of variables, how much you do want to hide ? for example --- for 4 how many and for 20 how many ?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @Alice TLD is domain extension, for example it can be .com  .co.uk. .edu, com.br, .website, .club and much much more.

Comment: @Alice I always want to hide six character from the middle of the string.

Comment: so if it is 4-6 char string, you will hide all ?

Comment: How about you count the string length of x section in your string and and replace x percentage of them with asterix's.

Comment: @Alice Yeah. But its to hard to have a 6 char string in a domain. Almost all will have at least 10 characters.

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden How can i do this? Do you have an example?